# hdparm -S60 /dev/sda (Works fine, but every 30 mins HDD wakes up and spins down even though not in use.)

Tags: sleep, hdparm

Seagate 4TB 3.5".

```
$ hdparm -S60 /dev/sda
```

OK. 5 mins after no access on HDD, it spins down. No problem.

But every 30 mins it wakes up by itself without any event, and goes to bed immediately. I have to wake up in the middle of night because of its spinning up sound.

Comment: What is your operating system? What services are running, and what is the output of tail /var/log/messages ?

Comment: Do you have a swap partition on that HDD?

Comment: @Nils, Armbian. Default services. /var/log/messages is full of rsyslog retry msgs.

Comment: @dirkt, Oops. It's the external HDD NTFS with truecrypted big file in it mounted. No SWAP.

Comment: Is it possible that either the NTFS kernel driver or truecrypt accesses the disk regularly for some reason? What happens if you disable truecrypt, and just mount the NTFS?